# Greying out past dates

Tags: jquery

I have tried this jQuery code to grey out past dates, but it doesn't give the right output; I can still select past dates.

```
$('.calendar').datepicker({minDate: 0}).live('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).prev('input').val(
      (ev.date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + 
      ev.date.getDate("option", "minDate", 0) + '/' +    
      ev.date.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)
    );
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

Comment: A better way to look at it is not graying today's date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to implement it:

```
 $(function(){ $('#datepicker1').datepicker({ startDate: '-0m'}).on('changeDate', function(ev){ $('#datepicker1').datepicker('hide'); }); });
```

instead of using minDate you can use startDate

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the minDate as current date

```
var date = new Date();
var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
var currentDate = date.getDate();
var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

$('.calendar').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
});
```

Comment: what is point of dissasembling date, just to put it back together again with same variables? is exact same as `minDate: new Date()`

Comment: both minDate: 0  and minDate: new Date() are not working for me...
Is there any other solution for this problem..